# ASP.NET [Object data source]

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I send id of my class object from one page to second this way :

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "ItemDetail.aspx?itemId=" + (string)Eval("Id") %>'
```

Then I get the object with ObjectDataSource and function this way :

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceItem" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetItem"
            TypeName="Catalog">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="itemId" QueryStringField="itemId" Type="string" DefaultValue="" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

So how to use this item in my new page code :

```
this.ObjectDataSourceItem.?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the ObjectDataSource's [Selected event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selected.aspx), access the [ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasourcestatuseventargs_members.aspx) ReturnValue property (e.ReturnValue), and cast it to the appropriate type. Something like:

```
protected void ObjectDataSourceItem_Selected(object source, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    var myDataSet = (DataSet)e.ReturnValue;
}
```